# Is any research being done in penguin chess? Especially, is there a tablebase?

Tags: chess-variants

First here are the rules for penguin chess. Everything is the same as in normal chess, except:

1. Any piece, except the kings, can move to any empty square.
2. Pawns can't move to the 1st and 8th rank.

I have explored some, rather basic, endgames.
Obviously, there are easy checkmates, like K+Q vs K, K+R vs K or K+B+b vs K. However even K+N+N vs K, which normally isn't winning. For example:

```
[FEN "6k1/3N4/3N2K1/8/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1"]
```

is clearly winning. If it's White to move, white wins with: Nd6-e7+, Kh8, Nd7-f7#. Another interesting position, which I figured out is a draw, is K+R vs K+P. Here Black's main idea is to move the pawn to 2nd rank and the rook is unable to defend the first rank and simultaneously attack the Black king.

I'm asking if there has been any kind of development in penguin chess. If there exist forums, I would appreciate them as well.

Comment: Your question is currently far too broad. It invites a long essay type answer which is not suitable for this site. Please edit it to make it more specific. The Help Center - https://chess.stackexchange.com/help - gives more useful information on what is appropriate.

Comment: I'm sorry but why is my question too broad? I asked whether there exists a tablebase for penguin chess or that there are forums discussing penguin chess.

Comment: You also ask "I'm asking if there has been any kind of development in penguin chess.". So, a total of 3 questions when only one is allowed per question.